# About executable with debug information in windows

Tags: debug-symbols, portable-executable

**PointerToSymbolTable**:

> The file offset of the COFF symbol
>   table, or zero if no COFF symbol table
>   is present. It is 0 for PE image
>   files, since debugging information is
>   depreciated.

Why it says debugging information is depreciated for PE image? AFIAK, executables in windows can also carry debug information,isn't that the case?

Answer (score 2):

As it says debugging information is depreciated for PE image, debug symbols are not directly embedded in PE anymore. It's rather stored in a .PDB file that holds the debugging information. The format of this file is undocumented so the only you can extract the information from this file is by calling APIs in DbgHelp.dll.

Answer (score 1):

Note sure where you're reading that from, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680313%28VS.85%29.aspx) in MSDN has no such caveat.

You need to remember that MSDN is somewhat Microsoft-specific. And in Microsoft-world, coff debugging information has long since been replaced by .PDB files, so you almost never get symbols *inside* the executable image when you use a Microsoft compiler (and hence `PointerToSymbolTable` will always be 0).

There are still programs that use embedded COFF data (such as MinGW, I believe).

Comment: What's the structure name for debug symbols in PE?